# Is possible to add waypoints to Google Maps API without using JSON?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, google-maps

I'm on ASP.NET MVC and I'm using Google Maps API with Javascript.  I send a Model to the View with one or more waypoints to add to the route.

```
        function calcRoute() {
        initialize();
        var start = "<%= Model.StartAddress %>";
        var end = "<%= Model.ClientAddress %>";

        var waypts = [];

        waypts.push({
            location: "<%= Model.PickupAddress[0] %>",
            stopover:true
        });

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Is it possible to add waypoints this way with the addresses in Model.PickupAddress array?  I have seen examples code by using JSON (for markers), but if I can do it directly in this Javascript code, that's fine for me.

Comment: That is archaic.  However, it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  JSON is simply a lightweight or shortform way of specifying javascript objects.  It would be better to see an XHR to retrieve some values.  Because it seems that every view that is refreshed will have this code.  How about multiple addresses?

Comment: That's right, it's not very clear.  I was wondering if I could use JSON to fill the waypoints array.  But to solve this problem, we used a ASP foreach loop throught the addresses in PickUpAddress array.  I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works.